# Spring Security - Custom Principal from JWT

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, principal

Im using oauth2 and sso in my angular application. My rest backend verify the authentication token which is send by every request. Now I wanna use the oid claim to load the user from my database and save it in the principal. Also I wanna add the user authorities in the "GrantedAuthorities".

FooService

```
[...]
public Foo getFooByOid(String oid) throws FooNotFoundException {
    return fooRepository.findByOid(oid)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new FooNotFoundException("Foo with oid: " + oid + " not found"));
}
```

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> {
            oauth2.jwt();
        });
    }   
}
```

The spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri and spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri are defined in application.properties

After that my principal contains all the claims, headers and the token:

[Principal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L959v.png)

Can any one help me how to do? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The answer from Gary Archer is correct, but it has some pitfalls.

A full simple example in Kotlin:

The user interface, which is specific to your application:

```kotlin
interface User  {
    val id : String
    val email : String
    val displayName : String
    val avatar : String
    val roles : Set<String>
    val domain : String
        get() = this.email.split('@').last()
}
```

A principal should implement this interface:

```kotlin
class ClaimsNotFull(claim: String) : Exception("Claims not full, not found $claim")

data class IdelPrincipal(
    override val id: String,
    override val email: String,
    override val displayName: String,
    override val avatar: String,
    override val roles: Set<String>,
) : User {
    companion object {
        fun fromJwt(jwt: Jwt): IdelPrincipal {
            fun loadClaim(key: String): String = jwt.claims.getOrElse(key) {throw ClaimsNotFull(key)} as String
            return IdelPrincipal(
                id = jwt.subject,
                email = loadClaim("email"),
                displayName = loadClaim("displayName"),
                avatar = loadClaim("avatar"),
                roles = loadClaim("roles").split(",").toSet()
            )
        }

        fun copyToClaims(user : User, jwt: JWTClaimsSet.Builder) : JWTClaimsSet.Builder {
            return jwt.subject(user.id)
                .claim("email", user.email)
                .claim("displayName",user.displayName)
                .claim("avatar",user.avatar)
                .claim("roles",user.roles.joinToString(","))
        }
    }

}
```

Custom token and JwtConvertor:

```kotlin
class IdelAuthenticationToken(val jwt: Jwt, val user: IdelPrincipal) :
    AbstractAuthenticationToken(IdelAuthorities.from(user.roles)) {

    override fun getCredentials() = jwt // borrowed from JwtAuthenticationToken

    override fun getPrincipal() = user

    override fun isAuthenticated() = true // decoding of jwt is authentication
}

class IdelPrincipalJwtConvertor : Converter<Jwt, IdelAuthenticationToken> {
    override fun convert(jwt: Jwt): IdelAuthenticationToken {
        val principal = IdelPrincipal.fromJwt(jwt)
        return IdelAuthenticationToken(jwt,principal)
    }
}
```

Configure Spring Security:

```kotlin
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.authorizeRequests {
            it.anyRequest().authenticated()
        }
            .csrf{it.ignoringAntMatchers("/token")}
            .oauth2ResourceServer {it.jwt()}
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt {cstm ->
                cstm.jwtAuthenticationConverter(IdelPrincipalJwtConvertor())
            }
        http.exceptionHandling {
            it
                .authenticationEntryPoint(BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .accessDeniedHandler(BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler())
        }
        http .sessionManagement {it.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)}
        http.anonymous().disable()
}
```

And a method in your controller for testing:

```kotlin
    @GetMapping("/me2")
    fun me2(@AuthenticationPrincipal user : User) : User {
        val result = MeResult(
            id = user.id,
            domain = user.domain,
            displayName = user.displayName,
            avatar = user.avatar,
            email = user.email,
            authorities = user.roles.toList()
        )
        return user
    }
```

That's return:

```json
{
    "id": "10777",
    "email": "leonid.vygovsky@gmail.com",
    "displayName": "Leonid Vygovskiy",
    "avatar": "",
    "roles": [
        "ROLE_USER"
    ],
    "domain": "gmail.com"
}
```

Comment: This is correct since it avoids re-validating the jwt by yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via a custom AuthenticationManager, if you write code such as this:

```
.oauth2ResourceServer.authenticationManagerResolver(request -> new CustomAuthenticationManager(request));
```

The properties you set on oauth2ResourceServer influence the behaviour of Spring's [BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/oauth2/oauth2-resource-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java)

You will then need to validate the JWT yourself, plus add your custom claims handling on top, then cache results for subsequent requests with the same token, which is tricky.

**EXAMPLE OF MINE**

I have a fairly complete sample that behaves like this, which can run on your PC and which you can maybe borrow some ideas from - it is quite an advanced sample though:

- [Spring Security Configuration](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/host/startup/HttpServerConfiguration.java)